# Error en Yii2, Setting unknown property: kartik\widgets\DatePicker::saveFormat

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2

Ayuda, estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Yii2. Todo me funciona bien al momento de ver y enviar a guardar. Pero tengo el siguiente error al momento de querer entrar a modificar un registro, le doy clic al botón para ir al formulario de modificar y me aparece lo siguiente, copio y pego para que puedan ver.

```
Unknown property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Setting unknown property: kartik\widgets\DatePicker::saveFormat
12.
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Method kartik\builder\TabularForm::kartik\builder\{closure}() does not exist' in C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php:199
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(199): ReflectionMethod->__construct('kartik\\builder\\...', 'kartik\\builder\\...')
#1 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\views\errorHandler\callStackItem.php(26): yii\web\ErrorHandler->addTypeLinks('kartik\\builder\\...')
#2 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(328): require('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...')
#3 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(250): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...', Array)
#4 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(253): yii\base\View->renderFile('@yii/views/erro...', Array, Object(yii\web\ErrorHandler))
#5 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(308): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderFile('@yii/views/erro...', Array)
#6 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(329): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderCallStackItem(NULL, NULL, 'kartik\\builder\\...', 'kartik\\builder\\...', Array, 12)
#7 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\views\errorHandler\exception.php(381): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderCallStack(Object(yii\base\UnknownPropertyException))
#8 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(328): require('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...')
#9 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(250): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...', Array)
#10 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(253): yii\base\View->renderFile('@yii/views/erro...', Array, Object(yii\web\ErrorHandler))
#11 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(114): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderFile('@yii/views/erro...', Array)
#12 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\UnknownPropertyException))
#13 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\base\UnknownPropertyException))
#14 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: kartik\widgets\DatePicker::saveFormat' in C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:201
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(525): yii\base\Component->__set('saveFormat', 'php:Y-m-d')
#1 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(kartik\widgets\DatePicker), Array)
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#3 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(381): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#4 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('kartik\\widgets\\...', Array, Array)
#5 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('kartik\\widgets\\...', Array, Array)
#6 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Widget.php(136): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#7 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-builder\BaseForm.php(458): yii\base\Widget::widget(Array)
#8 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-builder\BaseForm.php(305): kartik\builder\BaseForm::renderRawInput('Tubos[0][tfecha...', 'tubos-0-tfecha', Array)
#9 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-builder\TabularForm.php(363): kartik\builder\BaseForm::renderInput('Tubos[0][tfecha...', Array)
#10 [internal function]: kartik\builder\TabularForm->kartik\builder\{closure}(Array, 0, 0, Object(kartik\grid\DataColumn))
#11 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\DataColumn.php(219): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Array, 0, 0, Object(kartik\grid\DataColumn))
#12 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\DataColumn.php(233): yii\grid\DataColumn->getDataCellValue(Array, 0, 0)
#13 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-grid\DataColumn.php(331): yii\grid\DataColumn->renderDataCellContent(Array, 0, 0)
#14 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(507): kartik\grid\DataColumn->renderDataCell(Array, 0, 0)
#15 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(476): yii\grid\GridView->renderTableRow(Array, 0, 0)
#16 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-grid\GridView.php(1000): yii\grid\GridView->renderTableBody()
#17 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(347): kartik\grid\GridView->renderTableBody()
#18 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\BaseListView.php(155): yii\grid\GridView->renderItems()
#19 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(316): yii\widgets\BaseListView->renderSection('{items}')
#20 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\BaseListView.php(130): yii\grid\GridView->renderSection('{items}')
#21 [internal function]: yii\widgets\BaseListView->yii\widgets\{closure}(Array)
#22 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\BaseListView.php(133): preg_replace_callback('/{\\w+}/', Object(Closure), '<div class="pan...')
#23 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(291): yii\widgets\BaseListView->run()
#24 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-grid\GridView.php(971): yii\grid\GridView->run()
#25 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Widget.php(139): kartik\grid\GridView->run()
#26 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-builder\TabularForm.php(431): yii\base\Widget::widget(Array)
#27 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-builder\TabularForm.php(195): kartik\builder\TabularForm->renderGrid()
#28 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Widget.php(139): kartik\builder\TabularForm->run()
#29 C:\wamp64\www\yii\views\troncales\_formTubos.php(60): yii\base\Widget::widget(Array)
#30 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(328): require('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...')
#31 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(250): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...', Array)
#32 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(152): yii\base\View->renderFile('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...', Array, NULL)
#33 C:\wamp64\www\yii\views\troncales\_form.php(47): yii\base\View->render('_formTubos', Array)
#34 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(328): require('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...')
#35 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(250): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...', Array)
#36 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(152): yii\base\View->renderFile('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...', Array, NULL)
#37 C:\wamp64\www\yii\views\troncales\update.php(19): yii\base\View->render('_form', Array)
#38 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(328): require('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...')
#39 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(250): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...', Array)
#40 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(152): yii\base\View->renderFile('C:\\wamp64\\www\\y...', Array, Object(app\controllers\TroncalesController))
#41 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(381): yii\base\View->render('update', Array, Object(app\controllers\TroncalesController))
#42 C:\wamp64\www\yii\controllers\TroncalesController.php(94): yii\base\Controller->render('update', Array)
#43 [internal function]: app\controllers\TroncalesController->actionUpdate('1')
#44 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#45 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#46 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('update', Array)
#47 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('troncales/updat...', Array)
#48 C:\wamp64\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#49 C:\wamp64\www\yii\web\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#50 {main}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Comment: En la documentación del widget no viene dicho metodo de "saveFormat", de donde lo sacaster?

Comment: A parte del error deberias mostrar tu codigo pero solo las partes involucradas con ese error. Y para formatear el codigo, usa `ctrl+k` o el icono `{}`

Comment: @Sergio1871 pude solucionar :D Resulta que al momento de crear el objeto DatePicker estaba declarando el método saveFormat, tal como me lo señalaste. Solamente tuve que borrar estas dos líneas de código: 
'saveFormat' => 'php:Y-m-d',
'ajaxConversion' => true,

Y listo, solucionado el error. Gracias por su pronta respuesta.

Comment: @lois6b pude solucionar :D ya detallé la solución, gracias por la pronta respuesta.

Comment: Si ya quedo solucionado puedes poner la solución como respuesta por si alguien tiene la misma duda pueda encontrar la solución más fácilmente

Comment: @EfrainRivera, me alegro que encontraras la solución. Te recomiendo **[responder a tu propia pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)** y luego puedes **[aceptar tu propia pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**. Esto ayudará a futuros usuarios. Gracias.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave listo, ya lo hice. Pero gracias por la recomendación, ahora debo esperar 48 horas para aceptar mi propia respuesta.

Comment: @EfrainRivera gracias por contribuir en Stack Overflow en Español. una vez pasen las 48 horas _tal como dices_, podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar :D Resulta que al momento de crear el objeto DatePicker estaba declarando el método saveFormat y ajaxConversion. Que al parecer no existen en la clase DatePicker. 
Solamente tuve que borrar estas dos líneas de código:

```
'saveFormat' => 'php:Y-m-d', 
'ajaxConversion' => true,
```

Y listo, solucionado el error.